# Is there MySQL syntax for joining more than three tables when inserting?

Tags: mysql

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO film_new
(SELECT title, rental_rate,length,film_id,length,release_year FROM film)
JOIN film_actor
    ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
JOIN actor
    ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
```

and I get the error

> JOIN is not expected

Comment: The ```JOIN``` clause should also be a part of the sub-query, like, ```INSERT INTO film_new (SELECT title, rental_rate,length,film_id,length,release_year FROM film JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id)```. Did you try this way ?

Comment: You don't appear to be selecting anything from the joined tables so do you really need them at all? If so add table definition, sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that? `INSERT`  with `JOIN` makes no sense, and the given query does not use the `JOIN` for the `SELECT`  parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all brackets!

```
INSERT INTO film_new
SELECT title, rental_rate, length, film_id, length, release_year
FROM film
JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
```

I have just reformatted your query to make it readable, and removed brackets to make it syntactically correct.

However, your select columns look incorrect, especially that you don't seem to be selecting anything from the joined tables.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your parenthesis syntax here is wrong, instead of

```sql
INSERT INTO film_new 
(SELECT title, rental_rate,length,film_id,length,release_year FROM film) 
JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id 
JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id;
```

you should enclose the inner query completely, like

```sql
INSERT INTO film_new 
(SELECT (title, rental_rate,length,film_id,length,release_year) FROM film
JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id 
JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id)
```

The reason SQL is telling you that JOIN is not expected is because it is not part of the inner query (due to the way you put parentheses) but on the outer one, which in turn does not have a FROM clause, and therefore does not accept any join.